# Looper: old Joe & wife get a child?

Tags: time-travel, looper

When old Joe

> kills the first child that could be the 'Rainmaker',

you see a flashback where he is in bed with his wife and you hear the crying of a child.

Old Joe has mentioned that they did not have children and that his wife would have made a wonderful mother.

Did killing the first child alter the future where Joe & wife would have a child?

Answer (score 3):

In a story where time travel is concerned, particularly one where temporal loops and recursive paradoxes comprise a significant part of the tale, it will be difficult to make anything other than speculation based on what we are shown.

- When Old Joe kills the first child he experiences a temporal memory change where his wife and he wake to the sound of a crying child. We do not see the child, but it is inferred his wife was able to conceive.
- There is no way to know how the murdered child could have affected the events without having more history about him. He did, however live in a suburb, unlike many of the people we have seen up to this point. This implies an enhanced quality of life for the child and his parents.
- It is also possible his parents may have had an effect on the timeline which could have affected Joe or his wife which changed when the child died.
- Though the timeline does not last long, there may have been some relationship between the child, his parents, or someone they interact with which affects Joe or his wife in some way in which she ends up having a child.

Answer (score 0):

Way late on this but the reason, in my figuring, is that young Joe is getting clean now, in the present of 2044, rather than in the late 2060s.

The scene where old Joe explains that they tried for a long time but never managed to conceive was interspersed with flashbacks (flashforwards? Who knows, this time travel stuff can just fry your brain like an egg) of his withdrawal and hypo recovery. I think the suggestion there is that old Joe’s near life long drug addiction left his sperm count irreversibly damaged. But since his memories are just one possible eventuality now the shift in temporal events are such, at this juncture in the film, that he will still meet his future wife but with the damage to his sperm count no longer done due to having been drug free most of his life.

I think the film suggest the child’s death is a decisive factor only in its unfortunate placement in the scene progression and that we should focus more on how specifically young Joe is affecting old Joe and less on how the past in general is affecting old Joe.